# Gradle -v command points to old version

Tags: powershell, gradle, updates

Currently I'm trying to update Gradle 2.0 to 2.11. In the `getting-started.html` file of my gradle distribution (2.11) is described how to install a newer Gradle version. I unpacked the .zip to the desired location and unpacked it. I set the environment variable `GRADLE_HOME` accordingly and it is included in the `PATH`.

However `gradle -v` will print:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-07-01 07:45:34 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     b6ead6fa452dfdadec484059191eb641d817226c
```

I checked my environment variable by using `Get-Childitem env:GRADLE_HOME`, which does print:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
GRADLE_HOME                    C:\dev\programs\gradle-2.11
```

Restarting PowerShell or even the computer didn't help. I've also set a variable pointing to `GRADLE_USER` (which is to a .gradle folder) is there a known issue with that? Or did I just miss something in the Installation process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell will run executables without a path only if they're located in one of the folders listed in the `PATH` environment variable (`$env:Path` in PowerShell). Most likely you still have the path to the old installation listed there (something like `...;C:\dev\programs\gradle-2.0\bin;...`). Depending on where it's defined you need to change it in the system or your user environment.

You can avoid the need to update the `PATH` environment variable with every Gradle update by using the `GRADLE_HOME` environment variable in it. However, for this to work you must make the respective registry value a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value (default is `REG_SZ`). The system environment is stored in this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

The user environment is stored in this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
```

You can change the type of the `PATH` value to `REG_EXPAND_SZ` with something like this:

```
$key  = 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment'
$path = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::GetValue($key, 'PATH', $null)
$path += ';%GRADLE_HOME%\bin'
[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::SetValue($key, 'PATH', $path, 'ExpandString')
```

or (a little more elaborate) like this:

```
$key  = 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment'
$path = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::GetValue($key, 'PATH', $null) -split ';' |
        Where-Object { $_ -notlike '*gradle*' }
$path = (@($path) + '%GRADLE_HOME%\bin') -join ';'
[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::SetValue($key, 'PATH', $path, 'ExpandString')
```

The latter will remove an existing Gradle path from the environment variable before adding the `GRADLE_HOME`-based path.

Change `$key` to the system environement key to modify the system instead of your user environment (requires admin privileges).

By putting `%GRADLE_HOME%\bin` in the `PATH` (and have the operating system expand the variable by making the registry value a `REG_EXPAND_SZ`) PowerShell will always use the `gradle.exe` from the `bin` directory in your `$env:GRADLE_HOME`.